# Add a laravel object captcha in a javascript script

Tags: javascript, php, web, captcha, laravel-blade

I need to add my captcha in a pop up but there are some stuff that need to be handled. 
first of all as i get the captcha from back-end its a php class, 
and secondly i need to add the object in an external js script,

so far i assigned the object to a variable in my blade file as below:

```
<script>
var captchaVar = '{!! NoCaptcha::display() !!}'
</script>
```

and for pop up  I have the following code in my script file

```
.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: '<div class="col-xs-12">\n' +
             '<div class="cr-item">\n' +
             '<label class="inl-blk">security code</label>\n' +
             '<div class="inp area inl-blk">\n' +
             + captchaVar + '\n' +
             '</div>\n' +
             '</div>\n' +
             '</div>',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
            $(this).submit();
        },
        cancel: function () {
        }
    }
});
```

I get NaN instead of *captchaVar* which should be

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
```

Comment: Can't you use `{!! NoCaptcha::display() !!} ` directly in the popup template?

Comment: no because its a laravel object and not accessible in my script file

Comment: Is the script file imported before or after the variable declaration?

Comment: I imported it after the variable's declaration. the thing is it produces NaN, and doesnt give an undeclared error

Answer (score 0):

```
.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: '<div class="col-xs-12">\n' +
             '<div class="cr-item">\n' +
             '<label class="inl-blk">security code</label>\n' +
             '<div class="inp area inl-blk">\n' +
             captchaVar + '\n' +
             '</div>\n' +
             '</div>\n' +
             '</div>',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
            $(this).submit();
        },
        cancel: function () {
        }
    }
});
```

There was a plus too much in your code. It then created the NaN instead of the expected result.